# Execute PHP in Joomla Article on-the-fly?

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

This is for Joomla 2.5.

There is a Joomla Article that needs to execute some PHP code to display as part of the Joomla Article. Is there a Joomla plug-in to allow embedding PHP code like which is supported in RSForm Pro with `and`?

Or is it better to have a Joomla module written with PHP and have it displayed as part of the Joomla Article? Are there Extensions to help with this, or would a Joomla module need to be written from scratch to do this? Thanks!

Comment: try http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051

Comment: check this http://www.walkswithme.net/how-to-include-html-or-php-codes-into-joomla-article

Answer (score 0):

As @Rakesh Sharma mentioned, there are plenty of extensions that allow you to add PHP to an article. That is the quick solution if you only need to add a bit of code on a single article.

If you may need to execute the same code again in another article then you should write an extension to do it. It can be done with a module using {loadposition}, but the preferred method of changing the output of a component is with a plugin. Then you would simply add the placeholder that triggers the plugin in the area you want to output to display.

We'd need more details on the code you want to execute to be able to give you the best solution.